# Hide the src string of an image tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

For example I have:

```
<img src="http://gateway.com/Providername/NameOfTheSupplier/RequestedImg.jpg" />
```

Now some customers are complaining that there customers can see the company name in the url. Because its to much work to change the structure of the gateway I use, I search for another way to do it.

Is there a way I can hide the src for the client? For example with base64, or another encryption that can decrypt client-side?

Comment: base64 should work. what is your problem then?

Comment: base64 is good but it suffers of some limitations with IE. I suggest you **pass by your server to download the image** (it'll download and cache it locally) then in the web page you'll see only a "local" URL to your server. Of course you have to **obfuscate original URL** but you can simply use an **hash**.

Comment: With MVC it should be easy to do with a controller method that returns a file and a single parameter (the hash). An internal table will translate the hash to the image URL, it'll then download and return to the client. If you obfuscate somehow (instead of using hash) you don't even need a lookup table.

Comment: I think downloading the images to the server and convert them to base64 is the only way. I just don't like the idea of downloading every image to the server, also when I use a storage function or something its still a lot of data to store ( about 1 million images ). I will cost me way to much storage and traffic. I think I need to find a solution at the gateway side.

Comment: You don't really need to store them in the server, moreover you can **redirect** to the right page (so your server will pay only for the request and not for the download itself). Clients will "see" the URL to your server but browser will get data from outside. With base64 you need to keep images less than 32kb.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but this requires you to download the image, convert to base64 and embed in the page (or CSS).

This increases the payload by about 34%.

---

An alternative is to use CSS to style the page, embedding the image URLs in the CSS. This tends to not be dynamic (though it can be) and still, anyone who knows a bit about web technologies can still view the CSS and see the URLs. Using images in this way is of course also not semantic and can break your page in unexpected ways, meaning you will need to expand more efforts on making things that should "just work", work.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: no.
Long answer: no.
Technical answer: Everything that is displayed by a browser needs to be translated to human readable* text in one way. You can obfuscate server side though.

*) human readable also includes very short names like `http://gateway.com/P/N/R.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your entire image in `base64` code. 
For this can use a tons of services available out there.

Just an example:

[Convert any image into a base64 string](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUw%2BDQo8aHRtbCBs
YW5nPSJlbiI%2BDQogPGhlYWQ%2BDQogIDx0aXRsZT5QcmV0dHkgR2xvd2luZyBMaW5lczwvd   
Gl0bGU%2BDQogPC9oZWFkPg0KIDxib2R5Pg0KPGNhbnZhcyB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ
9IjQ1MCI%2BPC9jY..."</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code

```
$('img').filter(function(index){return $(this).attr('src')==='';}).hide();
```

Comment: And then... there will be no images. I am assuming the OP still wants the images to show.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Handler for this. This way you can hide URL and if you want you can send image using base64 also with this or just write byte stream in response.

I think this should work and you can also control image path by just changing one piece of code.

Check this link: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34084/Generic-Image-Handler-Using-IHttpHandler

Thanks.